# RequestPermissions not showing dialog box xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin. I found lot of similar topics and i tried them. but non of them work for xamarin.

I added the permission in the AndroidManifest for OS below Android M

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I used [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=vswin) and implemented the code below.

```
string[] permissions ={Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage};
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Activity, permissions, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions doesn't show the dialog box.

Comment: What is the version of android device, as its supports only above Android 6.0

Comment: @MShah It's Android 8.1

Comment: Try to write your code in main activity, after LoadApplication(new App());

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for my problem

```
RequestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : Or u can use AlertDialog to ask for Permissions

Like :

```
string[] permissions ={Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage};


AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetTitle("Asking for permisstions");
builder.SetMessage("This app needs this permission to continue");
builder.SetPositiveButton("Request Permissions",(senderAlert,args)=>
{
  RequestPermissions(permissions,0);
});

builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel",(senderAlert,args)=>
{
 Toast.MakeText(this,"Canceled",ToastLength.Short).Show();
});

Dialog dialog = builder.Create();
dialog.Show();
```

**NOTE** : this will work on android 6.0 and above.

Comment: My problem was RequestPermissions(permissions,0); won't work. It should come from the system. It is not a custom dialog that we can create.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I have a problem with my VS which I can't run and test since I'm new to xamarin but wrote this in notepad and thought it might work since the problem is the dialog itself